# Vuetify Tabs width custom

Tags: vuetify.js

How to set the `v-tabs` width:100% as flexable width?

```
<v-tabs v-model="tab">
  <v-tab href="#tab1" style="width:50%;">tab1</v-tab>
  <v-tab href="#tab2" style="width:50%;">tab2</v-tab>
</v-tabs> 
<v-tabs-items v-model="tab">
  <v-tab-item :key="1" value="tab1">1111</v-tab-item>
  <v-tab-item :key="2" value="tab2">222222</v-tab-item>
</v-tabs-items>
```

My code doesn't working as width 100%.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me in Vuetify 2.6.6:

```html
<v-tabs grow>
  <v-tab>Tab 1</v-tab>
  <v-tab>Tab 2</v-tab>
</v-tabs>
```

The `grow` prop reference: https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-tabs/#props-grow